# how to compose two or more functions in python

Tags: python

I have these two functions:

```
def swap_joker1(afile):
    idx = afile.index(27)
    if idx == len(afile) - 1:
        afile[idx],afile[0]=afile[0],afile[idx]
    else:
        afile[idx],afile[idx+1]=afile[idx+1],afile[idx]
        return afile

def swap_joker2(afile):
    idx = afile1.index(28)
    afile[idx],afile[idx+1],afile[idx+2]=afile[idx+1],afile[idx+2],afile[idx]
    return afile
```

how can I compose them together. and become a new function called cipher_functions?

Comment: Compose them how? As in apply function `swap_joker1` and then apply `swap_joker2` ?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac That's the standard definition of function composition, yes.

Comment: @chepner just to be sure.

Comment: Answered, and linked to a website, that should prove helpful in your future endeavours into functional programming as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few methods:

```
cipher_functions = lambda afile:swap_joker2(swap_joker1(afile))
def cipher_functions(afile):
    return swap_joker2(swap_joker1(afile))

import functional #third party, not maintained. Alternatives exist
cipher_functions = functional.compose(swap_joker1, swap_joker2)
```

Comment: +1 for reference to the `functional` module; I knew there was something available, but didn't look it up in time.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. Also, I suspect that the `functional` implementation may be faster than the homebrew version, which must have a lot of calling overhead. Of course, likely to be fastest in C.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can create your own cute function composition function:

```
import functools


def compose(*functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions)


def foo(var):
    return var // 2


def bar(var):
    return var + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Apply bar, then foo
    composition = compose(bar, foo)
    print composition(6)
```

You can apply the functions in whatever way you like, and in as many ways as you like. This answer was made possible, with the help of [this website](http://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if Python offered a composition operator. Unfortunately, you need to do it yourself.

```
def cipher_functions(afile):
    # This is f(g(x)); swap for g(f(x)) if necessary
    return swap_joker1(swap_joker2(afile))
```

You can define a composition function easily:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs))

cipher_functions = compose(swap_joker1, swap_joker2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap_joker1` function returns either `afile` or `None`, which make composition a bit hard.

Assuming it was actually:

```
def swap_joker1(afile):
    idx = afile.index(27)
    if idx == len(afile) - 1:
        afile[idx],afile[0]=afile[0],afile[idx]
    else:
        afile[idx],afile[idx+1]=afile[idx+1],afile[idx]
    return afile
```

Which returns `afile` unconditionally, you can simply write the composition as:

```
def cipher_functions(afile):
    return swap_joker2(swap_joker1(afile))
```

And more generally:

```
def compose(f, g):
    "Returns x -> (f o g)(x) = f(g(x))"
    def fog(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(g(*args, **kwargs))
    return fog

cipher_functions = compose(swap_joker2, swap_joker1)
```